# PlayFramework How to use redirect parameter?

Tags: playframework-2.1

How to hand over parameter?

user.name in User class

```
public static Result doregist() {

    Form<User> userForm = form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
    User user = userForm.get();

    return redirect(controllers.routes.Regist.complete("user.name")); 
}

public static Result complete(String name) {
    return ok(complete.render("name"));
}
```

Please answer. This source code complied error.

Comment: oh. i'm sorry. i pass this problem. Just "user.name" -> user.name , "name" -> name . this is typographical error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare method complete(String name) to the routes file as below

```
GET   /yourPath    controllers.YourClassAction.complete(name: String)
```